# Determine all positive integers $r$ such that there exist at least two pairs of positive integers $(m, n)$ satisfying the equation $2^m = n! + r$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine all positive integers $r$ such that there exist at least two pairs of positive integers $(m, n)$ satisfying the equation $$2^m = n! + r.$$

I have found that for $r=2$, we have $m=2,n=2$ and $m=3,n=3$ and for $r=8$ we have $m=5,n=4$ and $m=7,n=5$

Further, $r$ can not be odd. How we can prove in general. Please give some idea.

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of your previous edit to this question.

Answer (score 2):

If we have two distinct solutions , we have $$2^a-b!=2^c-d!=r$$

hence $$2^a-2^c=b!-d!$$ hence $$2^c(2^{a-c}-1)=d!\cdot (\frac{b!}{d!}-1)$$

WLOG $a>c$ and $b>d$

Because of $2^c>d!$ , $\frac{b!}{d!}-1$ must be even , hence $\frac{b!}{d!}$ must be odd.
It is easy to show that this is only possible , if $b=d+1$ and $b$ is odd. Hence the right side
reduced to $(d+1)!-d!=d\cdot d!$ , so we get $$2^c(2^{a-c}-1)=d\cdot d!$$ with even $d$

Because of $2^c>d!$ , $2^{a-c}-1$ must be smaller than $d$ , but contain every odd prime smaller than $d$ as a prime factor. This shows $d\le 4$ (if $d\ge 5$ even , the largest prime smaller than $d$ is at least $\frac{d}{2}$ because of Bertrands postulate , hence $2^{a-c}-1$ must be at least $3\cdot \frac{d}{2}>d$ , since the largest prime below $d$ is also at least $5$) , hence $d=2$ or $d=4$ giving the two posted solutions. Those are the only solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $r$ is such that there are two solutions $(m,n)$ and $(m',n')$ to the equation (all in positive integers). Wlog $n'\le n$.
If  $n=n'$, then also $m=m'$, hence  $1\le n'<n$, making $n!$ even. As already mentioned by the OP, it follows that $r$ is even.

Eliminate $r$:
$$ 2^m-2^{m'}=n!-n'!$$
As $2^m$, $2^{m'}$, $n!$ are even, so is $n'!$, i.e., we also have $n'\ge 2$ and from $n'!+r\ge 2!+2=4$, we have $m>m'\ge 2$.
Factor a little:
$$ 2^{m'}(2^{m-m'}-1) = n'!\left(\prod_{k=n'+1}^nk-1\right)$$
As $2^{m'}>n'!$, the expression in parentheses must be even, hence the product therein must be odd. This is only possible if $n=n'+1$ and $n$ is odd.
So the above simplifies to
$$\tag12^{m'}(2^{m-m'}-1) = (n-1)!\cdot (n-1)=(n-2)!\cdot (n-1)^2$$
Note that everything is determined by $n$ alone, i.e., not only $$n'=n-1,$$ but also
$$\tag2m'=v_2((n-1)!) + v_2(n-1),$$ $$r=2^{m'}-n'!,$$ and ultimately $$m=\log_2(n!+r),$$ which we hope to be an integer.
Manually checking small $n\in\{1,3,5\}$, we find the two solutions already given by the OP.
So henceforth assume $n>5$.

From $(2)$ and $2^{m'}>(n-1)!$, we find
$$n-1\ge 2^{v_2(n-1)}>\frac{(n-1)!}{2^{v_2((n-1)!)}}\ge \prod_{k=1\atop\text{odd}}^{n-1}\ge (n-2)(n-4), $$
contradiction.
We conclude that there are no further solutions.

Comment: How we have got $v_2$, that is, how we can write $m'=v_2((n-1)!)+v_2(n-1)$. please explain this fact

Comment: what is $v_2$ here? can you please explain?

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen,  I think the calculation in the extreme last position is not correct..There is some product involved, but there is no product after that only the product sign is threre.. Please explain.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen, please delete your post, please. It does not make any sense...

Comment: @ Haen von eitzen , please explain how  $$n-1\ge 2^{v_2(n-1)}>\frac{(n-1)!}{2^{v_2((n-1)!)}}\ge \prod_{k=1\atop\text{odd}}^{n-1}\ge (n-2)(n-4), $$